# i have javascript qustion, i want to know how could i ignore dash in regex for example if i typed spiderman i want it to be equal to spider-man

Tags: javascript, regex, reactjs, api, backend

In this code I am trying to compare the user input with my api result movie name, the problem is when the user enters spiderman there is no result in response because it's saved in the database as spider-man.
Here is my code where i want to apply regex to:

```
**onChangeNameHandler=(event)=>{
   const inputVal=document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value
   const optionsVal=document.getElementById('movies').childNodes

if(event.target.value.length >= 2){
  this.props.onOrderOPtions(event.target.value)
}
  for(let i=0;i<optionsVal.length;i++){
    if(optionsVal[i].value === inputVal){
      this.setState({optionalValue:optionsVal})
      this.props.onWatchMovie(inputVal)
    }
  }
  let newState=event.target.value
  this.setState({value:newState})
  }
  handleKeyPress = (event) => {
    if(this.state.optionalValue ===this.state.value){
    if(event.key === 'Enter'){
      this.props.onWatchMovie(this.state.value)
    }
  }
  }**
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are doing the search with js you need to remove dashes from both input value and the value you're comparing using the `.replace(/-/gi,'')` like:

```
for(let i=0;i<optionsVal.length;i++){
    if(optionsVal[i].value.replace(/-/gi,'') === inputVal.replace(/-/gi,'')){
      this.setState({optionalValue:optionsVal})
      this.props.onWatchMovie(inputVal)
    }
```